# Getting resources in a Visual Webpart

Tags: 2007, web-part, development, user-controls

I want to get resources that are kept at directory in my visual webpart "User Control" for SharePoint 2007:

```
C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\web server extensions\12\Resources
```

At the moment I am doing something like this but its not working,

```
<div style="float:left; width: 35%;">
      <asp:Label ID="lblabc" runat="server" Text="How to get resources here ??" />   
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have to pass like below in your code

```
<asp:Label ID="lblabc" runat="server" Text="<%$ Resources:SampleFile,keyName %>"/>
```

Comment: this doesn't work until I add Resources folder in my solution and also copy resource files to App global resources in Virtual directory of app